# Ошибка при тестировании PHPUnit Laravel - SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "users" does not exist

Tags: laravel, postgresql, phpunit, laravel-8

Хочу написать простой HTTP тест, суть которого просто проверить работоспособность открытия нужной страницы. На сайте предусмотрены разные права (админы и пользователи), поэтому есть необходимость аутентифицировать конкретного пользователя как текущего.

Вот код теста:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Tests\TestCase;

class CommonUserBaseHttpTest extends TestCase
{
    protected User $user;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->user = User::factory()->common()->create();
    }

    protected function tearDown(): void
    {
        $this->user->delete();
        parent::tearDown();
    }

    public function test_dashboard()
    {
        $response = $this->actingAs($this->user)->get('/dashboard/forms');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

При запуске выдает такую ошибку:

```
• Tests\Feature\CommonUserBaseHttpTest > dashboard
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
LINE 1: insert into "users" ("name", "email", "email_verified_at", "...
                    ^ (SQL: insert into "users" ("name", "email", "email_verified_at", "password", "remember_token", "role", "updated_at", "created_at") values (test, test, 2022-09-23 12:07:51, $2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi, PDwo8NdF3L, 1, 2022-09-23 12:07:51, 2022-09-23 12:07:51) returning "id")

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:742
    738▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    739▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    740▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    741▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 742▕             throw new QueryException(
    743▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    744▕             );
    745▕         }
    746▕     }

      +16 vendor frames 
  17  tests/Feature/CommonUserBaseHttpTest.php:17
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory::create()
```

В интернете советуют менять `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` на `Tests\TestCase` и добавлять `parent::setUp()`, но всё это у меня уже есть.

Ради интереса пробовал писать сырой sql запрос вида `DB:raw('SELECT * FROM users')` в тесте, на это он не ругался.

Структура папки tests:

- tests
- - Feature
- - - CommonUserBaseHttpTest.php
- - - ExampleTest.php
- - Unit
- - - ExampleTest.php
- CreatesApplication.php
- TestCase.php

Comment: Касательно ```DB:raw('SELECT * FROM users')``` понял что я просто создал query строку без выполнения самого запроса, поэтому он и не ругался

Answer (score 1):

Зашёл в phpunit.xml и в строке `<env name="DB_DATABASE" value="testing"/>` значение testing поменял на название своей базы данных. Починилося.